# Is there a way to evaluate second arg of assert only when assert fail?

Tags: c#

Sorry for this maybe obvious question. Is there a way to make a code work properly without an if statement (or the short form of it)? I use `ToString()` only for demonstration. a, b can be of custom nullable type with custom method called in second arg of Assert.

```
                String a = "";
                String b = null;

                Assert.IsNotNull(a, "b is" + b.ToString());
```

Comment: Can you explain what you want to happen? You can't ask us to tell you how to make illegal code to work. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for something like the null-conditional operator `b?.ToString()`?

Comment: Could you please answer my question? I want to understand what you're asking.

Comment: @EnigmativityI want to check is _a_ is null and only if it is true I want to call _b.ToString()_. Think about it as if _Assert_ works like _if_ or if normal-order evaluation is used for Assert.

Comment: @elgonzo looks like it works. if you suggest this as answer I accept it.

Comment: @KovalevRoman - But what does that mean? Are you saying you have some code that you only want it to run when `a` is `null` then run the code?

Comment: @Enigmativity yes. if test is success I haven't interest about message argument and I don't want to check this code on anything like null. But using .? is not bad compromise.

Comment: Would something like `a.IfNullExecute(() => Console.WriteLine(b.ToString()))` be useful?

Comment: @Enigmativity it can but not good look  in unit testing code. @ elgonzo take better solution. I forgot that C# have .? operator too after coding on Kotlin last month.

Comment: @KovalevRoman - Is the `.?` operator works for you then you haven't really explained your question very well.

Comment: @Enigmativity _.?_ is spike but is better then _if_ there. What I really want can be achieved only via _if_ operator(in C#) I think. My question was about is C# contains special assert statement or special operator for evaluate arguments when it is needed. Or is it a way to create it.

Comment: @KovalevRoman - The only way to avoid evaluating arguments is to use things like `Func<Value>` or `Lazy<Value>`. If the arguments are simple parameters in a method call then they are all evaluated.

Comment: @Enigmativity are you say it is possible to write own mAssert(arpgPred, argMsg) method which works via Func<Value> or Lazy<Value>? And Value isn't evaluate if argPred isn't evaluate in false?

Comment: @KovalevRoman - Yes, pretty much. I do struggle to understand exactly what you're saying, but yes.

Comment: @Enigmativity ok, it is spike too and forces to write ugly code like mAssert(a>b, Lazy<Int>a/b). But it is a way to create the behavior needed for me. Thanks.

Comment: @KovalevRoman - I don't know what you mean by "spike". And `mAssert(a>b, Lazy<Int>a/b)` isn't valid code. I really wish I could clearly understand what you're asking.

Comment: @Enigmativity by "spike" I meant "ugly bad code which works". If you know some language with late evaluate of args(when it needed) you can understand what I mean. For example in Common Lisp I can write function which operate with second _arg_ as a code: `(assert predicate '(<code for apply>))` or write a macros.

Comment: @Enigmativity What about Lazy and Func I thought that you mean smth like this: https://pastebin.com/HC5YbtHj

Comment: @KovalevRoman - I see now more what you're saying.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [overloaded method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243740.aspx) which takes a string with parameters:

```
Assert.IsNotNull(a, "b is {0}", b);
```

Comment: _ToString() only for demonstration. a, b can be of custom nullable type with custom method called in second arg of Assert_ 

try: `Assert.IsNotNull(a, "b is {0}", b.ToString());`